# How to have consistent ownership of mounted volumes in docker?

Tags: docker

I'm trying to understand some weird behavior that I'm seeing on docker. I want to run a container which writes cached data to a mounted volume from the host which I can later reuse for future executions of the container and that can also be read from the host.

On the host, I see that my user has the user id `1000`:

```
# This is on the host
$ id
uid=1000(juan-munoz) gid=1000(juan-munoz) groups=1000(juan-munoz)...
```

I'm running the container without any special flags for the user so it runs as `root`:

```
# This is on the container
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
```

Also, there is already a user with `id=1000`:

```
# The image is provided by AWS and apparently it includes a user with this ID
$ id -nu 1000
ec2-user
```

I have mounted a directory with `-v /some/local/directory:/var/mounted`. Locally, this directory is owned by my user (`id=1000`):

```
# On the host
ls -ld /some/local/directory
drwx------ 2 juan-munoz juan-munoz 4.0K Jun 21 16:21 /some/local/directory
```

In the container, if I go check the directory I see that it's currently owned by `root`. This is the first part that I don't understand.

```
# ls -ld /var/mounted
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Jun 22 03:36 /var/mounted
```

Why `root?` I would have expected that with the `mount` the user id would be respected.

If I then try to change the user to `1000`, this happens:

```
# Inside the container
$ chown -R 1000:1000 /var/mounted
ls -ld /var/mounted
drwx------ 2 ec2-user 1000 4096 Jun 22 03:36 /var/mounted
```

Which looks good to me, but when I do that, if I look at what happened on the `host` I see the following:

```
# On the host
ls -ld /some/local/directory
drwx------ 2     100999     100999 4.0K Jun 21 20:36 /some/local/directory
```

So either the host or the container has a messed up owner. If I `chown 1000:1000` on the host, the container sees it as `root`, if I `chown 1000:1000` on the container, the host sees it as `100999`.

What am I doing wrong here?

### Repro steps

```
$ mkdir $HOME/testing
$ docker run -it --name=ubuntu-test --entrypoint="/bin/bash" --rm -v $HOME/testing:$HOME/testing ubuntu:latest

# Inside the container
$ cd /home/myusername/testing
$ touch file.txt
root@b98b7a5445e3:/home/juan-munoz/testing# ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jun 30 23:52 file.txt

# Outside the container
$ ls -l $HOME/testing
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 juan-munoz juan-munoz 0 Jun 30 16:52 file.txt
```

Observed behavior:

- In some computers, from outside the container, the file is owned by the local user. In others, it's owned by root.

Expected behavior:

- To be consistent across computers

Comment: Do you perchance have [user namespace remapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/) enabled?  Are you on a native-Linux host, using the Docker engine directly?

Comment: Yeah the host is running ubuntu natively. I did install docker desktop for linux recently and I think that messed up some configurations but I don't know if it's related.

I read the `user namespace remapping` doc, thanks for that. I couldn't figure out whether it was enabled on the daemon but I tried using `--userns=host` on `docker run` to make sure it was disabled but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I feel like user namespaces may still be in play somehow. What's in your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`? Does `cat /proc/.../uid_map` for the container process show anything other than `0 0 4294967295`?

Comment: Please take a look at: [How to change the owner of VOLUME directory in Dockerfile?](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same issue under Ubuntu 22.04 with Docker Desktop installed. After the Docker Desktop is uninstalled and the Docker Engine is reinstalled, things just go the way I want them to: having consistent ownership of mounted directories between the host and the container.

Here is my use case: I want to start an Ubuntu 20.04 container and use it as the compiling environment for my application. The Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ARG USER=docker
ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000

# create a new user with same UID & PID but no password
RUN groupadd --gid ${GID} ${USER} && \
    useradd --create-home ${USER} --uid=${UID} --gid=${GID} --groups root && \
    passwd --delete ${USER}
# add user to the sudo group and set sudo group to no passoword
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y sudo && \
    adduser ${USER} sudo && \
    echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers
# prevent tzdata to ask for configuration
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive TZ=Etc/UTC apt -y install tzdata
RUN apt install -y build-essential git cmake

# setup default user when enter the container
USER ${UID}:${GID}
WORKDIR /home/${USER}
```

The building script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
UID=$(id -u)
GID=$(id -g)
docker build --build-arg USER="$USER" \
    --build-arg UID="$UID" \
    --build-arg GID="$GID" \
    --tag "ubuntu-env" \
    --file ./Dockerfile \
    --progress=plain \
    .
```

Since I use it as the compiling environment, the whole home directory is mounted for convenience:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e
docker run -it \
    --name "build-env" \
    --user "${USER}" \
    --workdir "${PWD}" \
    --env TERM=xterm-256color \
    --volume="$HOME":"$HOME" \
    --detach \
    "ubuntu-env" \
    /bin/bash
```

Somehow, with the Docker Desktop installed, the owner of the mounted home directory is always the root rather than the host user. After it is uninstalled, the mounted directory now gets the expected owner in the container, aka the host user.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the accepted answer because even though I still don't fully understand what's going on here, it's pretty obvious it has to do with Docker Desktop being installed. I removed docker desktop and now it behaves as expected. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it helps you. I wish I could explain why in addition to sharing my experience, but my knowledge of how volume works is quite limited (I tend to believe it's a bug from Docker Desktop since all its settings in the dashboard seem innocent).

Comment: I know this is old, but we had the same issue. The following link explains it: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/faqs/linuxfaqs/

Docker Desktop on Linux runs a Virtual Machine (VM) so creates and uses a custom docker context desktop-linux on startup.